# re enable panel shadow

Tags: compiz, gnome-panel

how can I re-enable panel shadow for both top and bottom? CCSM doesn't seems to work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done in CompizConfig Settings Manager that didn't work?

Comment: ive installed rgba before , since then , my panel does not have shadow even ive reset my ccsm =(

Comment: In the CCSM, try to navigate to Effects → Window Borders (maybe it's window decorations) and set the value for "Shadow for Windows" to "all". Does that do anything? You should also try to log out afterwards.

Comment: doesnt work =( any terminal tricks for this ?

Comment: I algo got the same problem after installing GNOME Color Chooser. I think the better idea is unistall it.

Comment: Well, I'e just uninstalled it and threr's still no panel shadow... :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure compiz is activated, then launch **ccsm** and go to **Window Decoration** (make sure it is activated too) and on **Shadow windows** type `any` (if you only want shadows on panel but not on windows, type `type=Dock`). If it is still not working, reset all the value in **Window Decoration**, just make sure **Shadow windows** = `any`. If it is still not working, go to **Window Rules** and make sure it is unactivated.

And if it still not working, make sure compiz is really activated and in **ccsm** go to **Preferences** and click on **Reset to defaults**, that will reset all the parameters of Compiz so if you have a lot of customs parameters you will lost all of them and will have to make them again but it will almost certainly solve the problem.

Comment: "Shadow windows = any" works for me (ubuntu 11.04 Gnome classic).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ccsm, try adding `Class=gnome-panel` to the windows option for decorations. Usually enabling rgba does not affect shadows.

*I'm also going to guess you are using emerald? If you are, install emerald-theme-manager, and modify the theme so that shadows are visible again.*

If you provide more information I will update my answer to suit.

Comment: it doesnt help either =(

Comment: ok , ccsm doesnt work at all , tried purge ppa to revert back also , nothing changed , its just the gnome panel does not hav any shadows , others are ok , just the gnome-panel =(

Comment: You didn't mention a ppa in your question. Can you please provide more information?